# Logging VS2010 unit test results in TFS 2008 not working

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, mstest, tfsbuild

The tests appear to run fine after compliation, but the results don't go anywhere. A .trx file is written and indicates all tests passing. Team Build thinks no tests have been executed and gives the dreaded "Partial Success" result. I suspect that TFS cannot publish the trx to the database for some reason...possibly because the VS2010 version of the test results is not backwards compatible with TFS 2008...?

I'm running the build with MSBUILD 4.0 and using version 10 of MSTEST.

I've read that using the previous version of MSTEST (version 9 with VS 2008) could help. I tried this...MSTEST rightly complained that the test assembly was built against a more recent version of the .NET framework.

Anyone else had success with this? What should I try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I didn't have the right Microsoft.TeamSystem assemblies in the GAC. The version 9 assemblies were there but not version 10. This likely is due to VS2010 being uninstalled / reinstalled out of order w/ VS2008 (or something, who knows). A "Repair Installation" setup step solved the problem.

So, it looks like MSTEST 10 can indeed post results to a TFS 2008 datastore. Wee!

Comment: On which machine did you need to add the assemblies to the GAC? the build server of the TFS server?